# I peform some task in console application when i call a form with a key combination its working

Tags: c#

explain step by step :
    i am making a windows application in which i am performing some task in  the console.
    related to keys 
    and in which when i call a form from console,its done 
    but after call a form thread is not returning in console why?
    any suggestion?

```
 if (Keys.Control == Control.ModifierKeys) Form1.crtl = 1;
                        if (Keys.K == (Keys)i) Form1.k = 1;
                        if (Form1.k == 1 && Form1.crtl == 1)
                        {
                            string response = ShowDialog("Password Required: ", "Password");
                            Form1 f = new Form1();
                            f.timer1.Enabled = false;
                            if (response.Equals("Password@123"))
                            {
                                Application.Run(f);
                                Form1.k = 0;
                                Form1.crtl = 0;
                            }
                        }


after i am performing some task but thread is not returning
```

Comment: `Application.Run` runs standard application message loop on the current thread. That's why console will not receive control until `Form` being closed. Refer [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If i am not using application.run then form control is not visible, for this reason i am using application.run. if you have nay alternative then tell me .